# Checking for concatenation in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

This is another prolog task that I can't solve at this moment. I have to write a predicat p(X,Y), where X is list of lists of number and Y is a list of numbers. The predicat has to verify:

1) if X can be presented as a concatenation between 2 elements from Y.
2) X has a odd number of elements. 
3) Sum of all elements in X is last element in Y.

Maybe as a separate tasks 2, 3 could be written easy. Problem is at 1)

Thank you in advance. I feel sorry for posting such an easy tasks, but prolog really drives me crazy. I have read all my lections over and over again. But the situation is similar to this:
school: 3+x=5, x = ?
exam: cos(x+y+z) + lim (5x+y)/t = .... If  you know what I mean. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for concatenations is done with `append/3`, which is more commonly used to build them but like many Prolog predicates works "in the opposite direction" as well. More specifically, `append(A,B,C)` checks whether `C` is the concatenation of `A` and `B`. So,

```
member(A, Y),
member(B, Y),
append(A, B, X)
```

checks whether there is a element `A` in `Y` and a element `B` in `Y` such that their concatenation unifies with `X`.

(Note that this does *not* check whether `A` and `B` are *distinct* elements of `Y`.)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Could 3) look like this:

sumlast(X,Y):- sum(X) = last(Y). Where sum finds sum(X) of all elements in X and last(Y) find last element in Y.

and solution for 1) and 3) would be:
P(X,Y):- member(A,Y),member(B,Y),append(A,B,X),sumlast(X,Y).

Comment: @borku: `sum(X) = last(X)` always fails in Prolog. There are no function calls; think relationally.

Comment: I'm very confused with all the languages around me: prolog, scheme, asp.net, c++, php, etc. I realize that I look like a moron. But I have a very big trouble with logic in prolog and thinking that way.

Comment: @borku: I'm not calling you a moron. Prolog is just quite different from most other languages. Using it correctly takes practice. Maybe studying [P-99](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/) might help?

Comment: I have 12 hours, wish me luck. Thank you!

Comment: Hello again,

sum([],0).
sum([X|L],N1):-sum(L,N), N1 is N+X.
sumList([],0).
sumList([L1|L],N1):-sumList(L,N), N1 is N+X,sum(L1,X).
last([X|[]],X).
last([_|L],X):-last(L,X).
p(X,[S|_]):-last(S,X1),sumList(X,X1).
p(X,[L|Y]):-p(X,Y).

What do you think? Looks pretty bad right here. You could paste it somewhere.